# Missing argument and undefined reference to PLASMA function during gfortran compilation

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a Fortran program that uses the [PLASMA libraries](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/software/). Compilation fails with **undefined reference to `__plasma_MOD_plasma_init'**. Inside plasma.h (which i assume plasma.mod is the interface for), plasma_init is defined with one argument whereas it is called with two in the Fortran program. When removing the second argument though, i get **Error: Missing actual argument for argument ‘info’ at (1)**. I haven't been able to make sense of this, so hopefully someone here can.

I'm using PLASMA 2.8.0 and gcc 6.3.0 20170516.

Here's the makefile. I tried including the pkgconfig which contains plasma.pc because i thought the function's implementation was missing.

```
#LIB_ROOT = path to the lib
INCLUDE_PLASMA := $(LIB_ROOT)/plasma_2.8.0/include
LIB_PLASMA := $(LIB_ROOT)/plasma_2.8.0/lib/pkgconfig

example: example.f90
    gfortran -o example example.f90 -I$(INCLUDE_PLASMA) -L$(LIB_PLASMA)
```

Here's the minimal Fortran code :

```
program example
  use plasma
  implicit none

  integer :: a = 1
  integer :: info = 1

  call plasma_init(a, info)
end program
```

In plasma.h, plasma_init is defined as:

```
int PLASMA_Init(int cores);
```

Comment: Well according to https://icl.utk.edu/projectsfiles/plasma/pdf/users_guide.pdf plasma_init from Fortran takes two arguments, CALL PLASMA_INIT( CORES, INFO ). Thus your compile error is because there is a missing actual argument for argument ‘info’. And no, the C header file does not define the interface for Fortran, it defines it for C; you will need to find the Plasma module and/or the documentation. I'm sorry but I can't help you with your linking error.

Comment: Ian Bush mentions the compiler error about the arguments, but for the linking: you aren't actually telling gfortran to link against any libraries.  Explaining how linking works is perhaps a little too broad for a question here, so please read look at the user documentation to see whether there's something mentioned in there about how to compile your program.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by correctly linking to the required libraries, here's the new makefile:

```
PLASMA_BUILD = [some directories]/plasma-installer_2.8.0/build
LIB_PLASMA := $(PLASMA_BUILD)/plasma_2.8.0/lib # contains libplasma.a, libcoreblas.a and libcoreblasqw.a
LIB_QUARK := $(PLASMA_BUILD)/plasma_2.8.0/quark # contains libquark.a
LIB_LAPACK := $(PLASMA_BUILD)/lapack-3.6.0 # contains liblapack.a and liblapacke.a
PLASMA_INTERFACE = $(PLASMA_BUILD)/plasma_2.8.0/control # contains plasma.mod

example: example.f90
    gfortran -o example example.f90 -lpthread \
    -L$(LIB_PLASMA) -lplasma -lcoreblas -lcoreblasqw \
    -L$(LIB_QUARK) -lquark \
    -L$(LIB_LAPACK) -llapacke -llapack \
    -I$(PLASMA_INTERFACE)
```